# wget undefined offset

Tags: php

I will admit that I've seen other questions similar to my issue.  However, I'm still at a loss of what the error means, let alone how to fix it.

When I execute a PHP script via browser, it works fine.  No errors are returned.  However, when it runs as a cron job via wget (or curl) my event handler reports:  "Undefined offset: 84"

```
function MLSEscapeValues($pieces){
   // escape all of the values in the array

   global $ExtraDebugInfo;  // additional argument for error handler

   $PieceCount = count($pieces);

    for($k=0;$k <= ($PieceCount-1);$k++){

        $ExtraDebugInfo .= "PieceCount = $PieceCount and k = $k and value = ".$pieces[$k]."<br>";
        $pieces[$k] = mysql_real_escape_string($pieces[$k]);

    }

    return $pieces;
}
```

I've verified that the indexed array contains data in every row, yet not all fields have values (expected).

Thanks for the assistance.

edit:

Sample Data of the $piece array

```
Pieces[0] = 2.57
Pieces[1] = 21-30 Years
Pieces[2] = Traditional
Pieces[3] = 208  
Pieces[4] = 
Pieces[5] = 0
Pieces[6] = Slab
Pieces[7] = 3
Pieces[8] = 0
Pieces[9] = 4
Pieces[10] = 
Pieces[11] = 1
Pieces[12] = City
Pieces[13] = Frame,Wood Siding
Pieces[14] = Central Electric,Heat Pump
Pieces[15] = County
Pieces[16] = Breakfast Room,Formal Dining
Pieces[17] = Directions
Pieces[18] = 2013-01-05T14:59:58.607
Pieces[19] = Ceiling Fan(s),Dishwasher,Rng/Oven- Electric,Smoke Detector
Pieces[20] = 
Pieces[21] = Sat Dish Allowed
Pieces[22] = 1
Pieces[23] = 1
Pieces[24] = Great Room
Pieces[25] = Earth Contact,Ranch
Pieces[26] = 1
Pieces[27] = 2
Pieces[28] = Attached,Front Entry
Pieces[29] = Central Electric,Heat Pump
Pieces[30] = 0
Pieces[31] = 
Pieces[32] = 
Pieces[33] = No
Pieces[34] = Walk-In Closet
Pieces[35] = agentid
Pieces[36] = Name
Pieces[37] = 800-555-1212
Pieces[38] = 
Pieces[39] = id
Pieces[40] = Name
Pieces[41] = 800-555-1211
Pieces[42] = 
Pieces[43] = Excl Right To Sell
Pieces[44] = 
Pieces[45] = Acreage,Level,Treed
Pieces[46] = 
Pieces[47] = 23828274
Pieces[48] = 1794131
Pieces[49] = 
Pieces[50] = Enclosed Porch,Main Floor BR,Main Floor Master
Pieces[51] = 11
Pieces[52] = 2012-08-20T14:51:09.967
Pieces[53] = 159900
Pieces[54] = 
Pieces[55] = 
Pieces[56] = Composition
Pieces[57] = 
Pieces[58] = 
Pieces[59] = School Dist
Pieces[60] = Elementary
Pieces[61] = Middle
Pieces[62] = High School
Pieces[63] = 
Pieces[64] = 2710
Pieces[65] = State
Pieces[66] = Temporarily Off Market
Pieces[67] = FirstName
Pieces[68] = E
Pieces[69] = 7000
Pieces[70] = Circle
Pieces[71] = Oak
Pieces[72] = Single Family
Pieces[73] = 2109
Pieces[74] = Private
Pieces[75] = Main Level,Laundry Room
Pieces[76] = 
Pieces[77] = 
Pieces[78] = 
Pieces[79] = 
Pieces[80] = City/Public
Pieces[81] = Cash,Conventional,FHA,VA
Pieces[82] = 1986
Pieces[83] = 99999
Pieces[84] = 
Pieces[85] =
```

Comment: Can you post the input array and the return array?

Comment: Yes, we need to know the initial value of `$pieces` and the returned value of `$pieces`. In my opinion, `for($k=0; $k < $PieceCount; $k++){` is more readable than this `for($k=0;$k <= ($PieceCount-1);$k++){`.

Comment: Usually wget/curl requests doesn't contain referer and user agent information, so if your script is using them, it will make a difference.

Comment: Just remember that mysql_real_escape_string has been deprecated

Comment: Sorry for the vague initial post.  I added sample data to the original question.  I do realize that mysql_real_escape_string() has been depreciated and plan to correct that in the future as time allows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information but you're `$pieces` have come from (or you are building) an *SQL query right?  Chances are the syntax is wrong and your return value from whichever database function isn't the array you were expecting.

First stop is to `echo` any errors to see if this is the case.

[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)
[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)
[mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)  <-- shouldn't be using this lot

Comment: No this actually is data imported from an external source via curl().  It's a specialized database provided by a vendor that isn't well...it's that friendly.  I can't speak more to it than that as I don't know much about it from their side.  I get an condensed encoded xml format feed that I import into my own mysql database.  I parse it into an indexed array that I pass to the function above, returning escaped values.

Comment: @Raythe Still at a loss as to your exact setup - when you fetch this data are you at any point trying to save it to an actual file?  The thinking being that when running the script via cron (IE. on the command line) the php interpreter is subject to a different set of permission on the file system and can't read/write.

Comment: I'm just taking the data and doing a "replace into" into a MySQL database.

Comment: @Raythe Then I'm unsure - there is nothing intrinsically wrong with the code you have posted so at this point we can only really guess.  On a side note if you wished to try an alternate solution to `MLSEscapeValues`, it's purpose could be accomplished with a single line `$pieces = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $pieces);`

Comment: seems that actually using array_map instead of my own function worked.  Thanks for sticking with this question!